# Combining checkbox with Split panel in Google Earth Engine to compare two images

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is it possible to include a checkbox within a Split Panel?

In my case, I'm comparing data from Sentinel 5 with nightlights. The default option is the images of NO2 from the Sentinel 5. The right panel shows data from 2020 and the left panel from 2019. When I select the checkbox, I would like to see the images from nightlights for the same periods, instead of NO2. If unchecked, it shows NO2 data.

Here is my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a84bf389db81358f5c42a5a422ddfe71

I'm new with this App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below script gives an example how you could approach it. The `during` nightlights will not work yet though, as the latest available imagery, as of now, is from `2020-01-01`.

```
var prior = ['2019-03-22', '2019-04-30']
var during = ['2020-03-22', '2020-04-30']

var leftMap = createMap()
var rightMap = createMap()
ui.Map.Linker([leftMap, rightMap])

var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel({
  firstPanel: leftMap,
  secondPanel: rightMap,
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  wipe: true,
  style: {
    stretch: 'both'
  }
})
updateMaps(no2)
ui.root.widgets().reset([splitPanel])


function createMap() {
  var map = ui.Map()  
  map.setControlVisibility({
    all: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true
  })
  map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair')
  var checkbox = ui.Checkbox({
    label: 'Show Nighlights',
    onChange: function(checked) {
      updateMaps(checked ? nightlights : no2)
    },
    style: {
      position: 'top-right'
    }
  })
  map.add(checkbox)
  return map
}

function no2(dateRange) {
  var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
    .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
    .filterDate(dateRange[0], dateRange[1])
    .median()
  var visParams = {
    min: 0,
    max: 0.0003,
    palette: '#000004, #2C105C, 711F81, #B63679, EE605E, #FDAE78, FCFDBF',
    opacity: 0.75
  }
  return ui.Map.Layer(image, visParams, 'NO2')
}

function nightlights(dateRange) {
  var image = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG")
    .select('avg_rad')
    .filterDate(dateRange[0], dateRange[1])
    .median()
  var visParams = {
    min: 0,
    max: 65,
    opacity: 0.75
  }
  return ui.Map.Layer(image, visParams, 'Nightlights')
}

function updateMaps(layerFunction) {
  leftMap.layers().reset([layerFunction(prior)])
  rightMap.layers().reset([layerFunction(during)])
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c14f01f5d5c53eeb825c867abe2dd9d1